# Proving eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a root for an annihilating polynomial $p(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the next statement I need to prove:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of a endomorphism $f$ and $p(t)$ an annihilating polynomial of $f$. Prove that $\lambda$ is a root for $p(t)$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption, there is a nonzero vector $v$ such that $f(v) = \lambda v$. Then $f^{2} (v) = f \circ f(v) = \lambda^{2} v$, etc.

Write $p(t) = t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \dots + a_{1} t + a_{0}$.

Then
$$
0
=
p(f) v
=
(f^n + a_{n-1} f^{n-1} + \dots + a_{1} f + a_{0}) v
=
(\lambda^n + a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1} + \dots + a_{1} \lambda + a_{0}) v
,
$$
that is, $p(\lambda) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $v$ is the associated vector. To say $p$ annihilates $f$ is to say that $p(f) = 0$, i.e., that for every $w$ in the domain of $f$, $p(f)(w) = 0$, Apply this notion to compute $p(f)(v)$, where $v$ is the eigenvector for $\lambda$. What does $p(f)(v) = 0$ tell you?

Comment: I meant $p(f) (v)$, but my brain wasn't in gear enough to type it right this early in the morning. I'll fix it.